# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field

Tags: laravel

```
public function index()
{
   $students = Student::all()->toArray();
   return view('student.index', compact('students'));   
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('student.create');//
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'first_name'            => 'required',
        'last_name'             => 'required',
        'Age'                   => 'required',
        'Address'               => 'required',
        'Grade_Level'           => 'required',
        'mothers_first_name'    => 'required',
        'mothers_last_name'     => 'required',
        'mothers_age'           => 'required',
        'fathers_first_name'    => 'required',
        'fathers_last_name'     => 'required',
        'fathers_age'           => 'required'
    ]);

    $student = new Student([
        'first_name'            => $request->get('first_name'),
        'last_name'             => $request->get('last_name'),
        'Age'                   => $request->get('Age'),
        'Address'               => $request->get('Address'),
        'Grade_Level'           => $request->get('Grade_Level'),
        'mothers_first_name'    => $request->get('mothers_first_name'),
        'mothers_last_name'     => $request->get('mothers_last_name'),
        'mothers_age'           => $request->get('mothers_age'),
        'fathers_first_name'    => $request->get('fathers_first_name'),
        'fathers_last_name'     => $request->get('fathers_last_name'),
        'fathers_age'           => $request->get('fathers_age')
    ]);
    $student->save();
    return redirect()->route('student.index')->with('success', 'New teacher data successfully added');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{

    $student = Student::find($id);
    return view('student.edit', compact('student', 'id'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'first_name'            =>  'required',
        'last_name'             =>  'required',
        'Age'                   =>  'required',
        'Address'               =>  'required',
        'Grade_Level'           =>  'required'
    ]);

    $student = Student::find($id);
    $student->first_name        = $request->get('first_name');
    $student->last_name         = $request->get('last_name');
    $student->Age               = $request->get('Age');
    $student->Address           = $request->get('Address');
    $student->Grade_Level       = $request->get('Grade_Level');
    $student->save();
    return redirect()->route('student.index')->with('success', 'Student data successfully updated');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
   $student = Student::find($id);
   $student->delete();
   return redirect()->route('student.index')->with('success', 'Data successfully deleted');
}
```

This is my Controller i dont know why im getting error, i have also other controller with the same function but it works fine. i just recently add this mothers name, age etc part but before it was just name,age address, etc and it works fine but after i add more fillable area's im getting this error

[and this is the error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CakRB.jpg)

```html
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <ul>
   @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <li>{{$error}}</li>
   @endforeach
  </ul>
 </div>
 @endif
 @if(\Session::has('success'))
 <div class="alert alert-success">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <p><strong>{{\Session::get('success')}}</strong></p>
 </div>
 @endif
 <div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <img class="data-img" src="{{asset('img/adddata.png')}}">
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="container student-create">
 <div class="students-info">
 <h3>Student's Personal Info</h3>
 <form method="post" action="{{url('student')}}">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm">
        <label for="Inputfirstname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <label for="Inputlastname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <label for="Inputlastname">Age</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Age" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm">
    <label for="InputAddress">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Address" placeholder="Enter Address">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm">
    <label for="InputAddress">Grade Level/College Level</label>
    <select class="custom-select" name="Grade_Level">
         <option selected="">Select Grade Level</option>
         <option>Day Care 1</option>
         <option>Day Care 2</option>
         <option>Kinder Garten 1</option>
         <option>Kinder Garten 2</option>
         <option>Elementary 1</option>
         <option>Elementary 2</option>
         <option>Elementary 3</option>
         <option>Elementary 4</option>
         <option>Elementary 5</option>
         <option>Elementary 6</option>
         <option>Junior Highschool 1</option>
         <option>Junior Highschool 2</option>
         <option>Junior Highschool 3</option>
         <option>Junior Highschool 4</option>
         <option>Senior Highschool 1</option>
         <option>Senior Highschool 2</option>
         <option>College Level Information Technology 1</option>
         <option>College Level Information Technology 2</option>
         <option>College Level Information Technology 3</option>
         <option>College Level Information Technology 4</option>
       </select>
   </div>
  </div>

  <h3>Student's Parents Info</h3>
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm">
        <label for="Inputfirstname">Mothers First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mothers_first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <label for="Inputfirstname">Mothers Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mothers_last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <label for="Inputfirstname">Mothers Age</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="mothers_age" placeholder="Enter Age">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm">
     <label for="Inputfirstname">Fathers First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fathers_first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm">
     <label for="Inputfirstname">Fathers Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fathers_last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm">
     <label for="Inputfirstname">Fathers Age</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="fathers_age" placeholder="Enter Age">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group submit">
      <button type="button submit" class="btn btn-success">
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Submit Data
      </button>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Table Structure

[Student Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgBQF.jpg)

i hope you could help  me and Thank in advance

Comment: can you add the student model and table structure?

Comment: i edited my question and added the table structure

Comment: You need to send data in 'fathers_age' field or you can make it null-able so that it not give error.

Comment: In student model you need to change 'fathers_Age' to 'fathers_age'.. it's case sensetive.

Comment: @Ankit in my case its just the case sensitive one is the issue i try to correct and it works fine now thank you for your answers KUDOS

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `fathers_age` field name to `fathers_Age`. Because you taken `fathers_Age` field in your database.